# Equivalent expression of xslt 3.0 to xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

im having this expression in using xslt 3.0

```
<xsl:template match="TratEqnt">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Sl" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 4">
           <xsl:copy select="..">
             <xsl:copy-of select="* except Sl"/>

             <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
           </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

but when i use xslt 2.0 which is the mandatory in my project the line <xsl:copy select=".."> is not working and a compiler error is shown. When im trying to transform the equivalent of this to xslt 2.0 im not getting the desired functionality. Do you know what to do? I have to use xslt 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
      <xsl:copy select="..">
         <xsl:copy-of select="* except Sl"/>
```

to

```
     <xsl:element name="{name(..)}" namespace="{namespace-uri(..)}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="../(* except Sl)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, change

```
       <xsl:copy select="..">
         <xsl:copy-of select="* except Sl"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
```

to

```
       <xsl:for-each select="..">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:copy-of select="* except Sl"/>
           <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
         </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:for-each>
```